# Ways to gain Admin from Non-Admin account?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, system-restore

Okay so I'd like to install drivers for my tablet and other programs into my work laptop, I did find a solution here.

But I have to get Startup Repair to fail, to repair my computer. Which It doesn't seem to do (*It will tell me to restart the computer to see if system restore worked instead*).

So I need to ask does anyone know how to Make system Restore fail on me, Or any other way to gain the Admin account from a regular account?

Comment: What kind of suggestions are you following that needs you to make your system restore fail

Comment: So really you just want to create and access an administrator account on Windows 7 from a non-administrator account.  Is this correct?

Comment: Essentially, yes I need Admin access from a non-admin account.

Comment: @Nero.Saiin Best to edit your question title to reflect this and see the answer below.

Comment: @Nero.Saiin You mentioned this is work computer and you don't have administrative rights over it. that is because your system admin doesn't want you to have admin rights over it. You better ask your system admin for it rather than trying to hack your way around it by asking internet. Which could have consequences you would regret

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I have to agree with @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - best to ask your IT guy first.

Comment: @DavidPostill Just calling it a "work laptop" does not necessitate that the question relates to corporate IT support and networks.  For example, I am typing on my "Work Computer" right now, but it belongs to me and has nothing to do with corporate IT.  It is a question of interpretation.

Comment: @Matthew <shrug> It's pretty clear that it is. Funny how you agree with the other comment (best to ask your IT guy first) and not with mine (Please talk to your IT department)

Comment: @DavidPostill No disrespect meant - Implied in the response was IF this is your employer's computer THEN contact IT first.  Your response seemed more direct so I responded more directly.  I have added this to the answer I have given below to try to make this clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WARNING - if you are using a computer administrated by your employer then you should not follow this answer.  Contact your IT support.  However, if this is your own computer and you cannot access the administrator account you can try this work around.

Don't bother trying to get the System Restore to fail.  There are other ways of getting to an administrator account.  The following method will allow you to add an Administrator Account to ANY windows system.

First get an installation disk for any version of Windows (note - a repair disk should work also, but I have only ever done this with the installation disk) - you can get one from the Microsoft website along with the Installation Media Creation Tool (Windows 10 is easy to get).  Load this to a DVD or a USB.

Now restart your computer and boot from the installation disk/usb.  DO NOT INSTALL WINDOWS, instead choose repair my computer.  The repair tool will search for installations and then give you an option to LOAD DRIVERS.

CHOOSE LOAD DRIVERS and navigate to `C:\Windows\System32` - now scroll down to the executable called `osk.exe`.  RENAME this `osk1.exe` -  Now scroll back up to the executable called `cmd.exe`.  Rename this `osk.exe`.  Cancel out of the repair tool and restart Windows.

What you have done here is to rename the Command Prompt as the On-Screen-Keyboard.  Now, when you get to the login screen, click on the button in the bottom left corner and select `Open the On-Screen-Keyboard`.  This will open an Administrator Command Prompt.

In the Command Prompt, type:

```
net user Dave /Add
net localgroup administrators Dave /Add
```

This will add an Administrator called Dave to your computer (no password has been created - you can do this later).

Now close the Command Prompt window and click change user.  Click on Dave and you now have access to the computer as an administrator.

IMPORTANT - Once you have done this you need to rename the two executable back to their original names.  Failing to do this could cause problems and will leave a way in for hackers.

Comment: @Matthew Help someone try something like this on their work computer and they will thank you once they get fired for violating their companies IT Security policies

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I have a work computer for my business - just because he calls it a "work computer" does not mean it is owned by his employer - this is not entirely clear from the question

Comment: @Matthew Don't you have admin rights over it ? Or would you ask `any other way to gain the Admin account from a regular account?` if it wasn't work provided computer ? OP wouldn't accept it but it's clearly a work provided computer to me. Have seen a lot of employees bring in their personal computer to work and claim this is my work computer and requesting support :p

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I hear you.  The same IT policies you refer to above would probably forbid the user's IT department from giving him support.  I am assuming the OP is using his own computer for work and is unfamiliar with administrating Windows OSs - but I will add a warning to the answer to make your point clear.

Comment: It's a Laptop given to me upon hire so I can take it home leave it at work. It's been frustrating not being able to install my harmless software on it, either way I am the only one held responsible for my actions. Plus I doubt I'll be getting noticed.

Comment: @Nero.Saiin So it is YOUR computer and it is NOT administrated by your employer?

Comment: Hehehehe....like we think we will never get hacked

Comment: @Matthew Didn't I tell you :D

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I'm confused.  What didn't you tell me?

Comment: Ok, still not sure if you have the legal right to perform this work around.  Ask with IT first ;)